# What exactly is the difference between <listview.Clear> and <listview>.items.clear in delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

I would like to know why are there 2 different ways of clearing out a listview. One is by calling `listview.clear` and other is `listview.items.clear`. Actually, this extends to many other VCL components too. which method must be used and why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ListView.Clear` is just a wrapper around `ListView.Items.Clear` with `ListItems.BeginUpdate`/`ListItems.EndUpdate`. look at the source:

```
procedure TCustomListView.Clear;
begin
  FListItems.BeginUpdate;
  try
    FListItems.Clear;
  finally
    FListItems.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

From the docs:

> The BeginUpdate method suspends screen repainting until the EndUpdate
>   method is called. Use BeginUpdate to speed processing and avoid
>   flicker while items are added to or deleted from a collection.

A better practice is to use `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` for speed and avoiding flicker.
But the main reason to use `ListView.Clear` is because using a "high-level VCL methods" (As well commented by @Arnaud) is always a good idea, and the implementation might change  (BTW, the method was introduced in D7).

---

**EDIT:** I have tested the `TListView` with **10k** Items (D7/WinXP):

- `ListView.Items.Clear`: ~5500 ms
- `ListView.Clear`: ~330 ms

Conclusion: `ListView.Clear` is about 16 times faster than `ListView.Items.Clear` when `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` is not used!

Comment: Actually, I don't think that `BeginUpdate` .. `EndUpdate` is of any help in the case of `clear`.

Comment: @Smasher Since `clear` release each object, it will notify each deletion to the VCL, unless the `BeginUpdate / EndUpdate` is used. This is the difference between the two, and why `Clear` is much faster than `Items.Clear`. It is always a good idea to call directly the high-level VCL methods, instead of going into the internal plumbing, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, +1 for "high-level VCL methods". that was exactly the expression I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.Clear` is a convenience method that calls `ListView.Items.Clear` internally. There is no semantic difference no matter which of the two you call.

I prefer the first one because it is shorter and it doesn't show the internal representation which is of no interest for me at this point.

Comment: I expect no performance issue. The one just calls the other with the `BeginUpdate` .. `EndUpdate` not making a difference in this case (imho).

Comment: `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate` makes a huge performance issue with `TListView`.

Comment: -1 for saying it is a mere convenience method without any other difference. There is clearly a difference.