# match list view items against array list in c#

Tags: c#, listview, arraylist, hashtable

I have an `ArrayList` that contains some `HashTables` , and I have a `ListView` that contains some items.

What I need is to match the array list with the list items.

If an item in the list view and not in the array list, then it should be removed from the list view.

If not in either the list view or the array list, then add it to list view.

This is some code:

```
 ArrayList online_list = users;
 foreach (Hashtable i in online_list)
            {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    item.Text = (string)i["u_name"];
                    item.Name = (string)i["id"];
                    item.ImageIndex = 0;
                    lstvUsers.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

This code adds all array list items to the list view without the check!

Comment: Are you still on 1.1 or why do you use ArrayLists and  Hashtables?

Comment: iam on 3.5 , i use them because i recive data from php webservice which return associated array and array of array so i have to use them if you know better solution point me to it,but still i need answer

Answer (score 0):

You could first [`clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) all items of the `ListView`, then add all in the `ArrayList`:

```
lstvUsers.Clear();
foreach (Hashtable i in online_list)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = (string)i["u_name"];
    item.Name = (string)i["id"];
    item.ImageIndex = 0;
    lstvUsers.Items.Add(item);
}
```

You should use [`ListView.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) instead of `ListView.Items.Clear`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170049/284240

**Edit**: Since you're adamant that you only want to remove items from the ListView that are not in the ArrayList and add items that are not in the ListView but in the ArrayList . That approach is significantly less efficient since you need to compare each item in the ListView with each item in the ArrayList (and vice-versa) instead of comparing nothing.

For example:

```
var addItems =  online_list
    .Cast<Hashtable>()
    .Where(ht => !lstvUsers.Items.ContainsKey((string)ht["id"]));
var removeItems = lstvUsers.Items
    .Cast<ListViewItem>()
    .Where(lvi => !online_list.Cast<Hashtable>().Any(ht => (string)ht["id"] ==lvi.Name));

foreach (var removeItem in removeItems)
{
    lstvUsers.Items.Remove(removeItem);
}
foreach (var addHashTable in addItems)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = (string)addHashTable["u_name"];
    item.Name = (string)addHashTable["id"];
    lstvUsers.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: i already do this now but since i refresh content every 3 seconds it make a flicker @ list view and remove any selection if i did one !

Comment: @SamyMassoud: You could also use [`ListView.BeginUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx) before `lstvUsers.Items.Clear();` and [`ListView.EndUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate) after the loop. That would be even faster.

Comment: all what you mentioned is very helpful stuff and it would prevent flicker problem but what i really need is (if i have in my list two items Samy and Tim , and when i have next update i have only Tim so what i need just remove Samy only from list without removing Tim)

Comment: @SamyMassoud: You know that your approach is less efficient than simply clearing the list and adding the items in your ArrayList? You have to compare each item in the ListView with each item in the ArrayList(f.e. 1000 * 1000) instead of comparing nothing.

Comment: @SamyMassoud: Edited my answer to show one way to remove/add only necessary items. But that would be really inefficient.

Comment: thank you for your answer i will test it when i go home and i will inform you back with results