# Multiple Line Addition in TMEMO

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi XE2 Project with 2 Buttons (Button1, Button2) and 1 Memo (Memo1).

My requirement is that on Button1 Click Some Text will be witten to Memo1 in the First Line (Line1). If I click again on Button1 Some New Text will be written in a New Line (Line2).

If I click on Button2 the Another New Text will be appended in Memo1 (After Last Line a new Line will be created). So I have written the following code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text :='Line1';
  Memo1.Lines.Text :='Line2';
end;
....
....
....
....
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text :='Line3';
  Memo1.Lines.Text :='Line4';
end;
```

But the problem is that only one line is showing with text as "Line1" on Button1FirstClick, "Line2" on Button1SecondClick and "Line4" on Button2Click. Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add more text to a memo control, call either `Append` or `Add`, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Line1');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Line2');
end;
....
....
....
....
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Line3');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Line4');
end;
```

If you need to clear the contents...

```
Memo1.Lines.Clear;
```

And if you wish to replace a line (only if the index already exists):

```
Memo1.Lines[2]:= 'Replacement Text';
```

To delete one of the lines...

```
Memo1.Lines.Delete(2);
```

Comment: Your `Clear` isn't quite right. `TMemo` has a `Clear` property; you don't have to use `Lines.Clear`. `Memo1.Clear;` works just fine, and is less typing.

Comment: @Ken I actually never knew that, 6 extra characters doesn't hurt much though, does the same thing.

Comment: I didn't downvote you for it. :-) I was just pointing out that it was there, and is technically the correct way to clear a `TMemo` control's content. Typing 6 extra characters isn't much, and it's actually less than that with Code Insight, but when there's functionality built in that does it, *and* you can save 6 keystrokes, *and* it makes your code more readable, I usually like to use it. It's like using a `TStringList` - when I have one named `SL`, I always write `SL[i]` to access things in a loop instead of `SL.Strings[i]`, even though they're functionally equivalent.

Comment: 'Tis the purpose of default array properties :D

Comment: Exactly. To lessen typing and make the code clearer, just like `TMemo.Clear` is designed to do. :-)

Comment: It depends on [`Delphi implementation`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10170049/960757) of a control I'd say.

Comment: My account gets banned displaying **“Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?**. I have read <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers> but I have not found the exact reasson. Please anybody mention my faults.

Comment: @Rubi after looking over your profile / activity, it's rather clear the reasons. I'm sorry this has to happen to you, but it's something that StackExchange sites do to keep their sites clean. This site isn't just another forum site like you might be used to. It appears that the downvote which someone issued to this question triggered this ban, after many other downvotes.

Comment: For example, this particular question of yours is very beginner level stuff. You can simply read Delphi's help topic for this control and discover for yourself before going and asking other people. Notice that when you hover your mouse over the downvote arrow of a question, it mentions "This question does not show any research effort...".

Answer (score 7):

`TMemo.Lines` is an object of type [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TStrings) that has many string handling capabilities. Assigning the `Text` property rewrites all strings it contains.

You can add a single line after all other already present lines with:

```
Memo.Lines.Add('Text');
```

You can insert a line (at fourth position) with:

```
Memo.Lines.Insert(3, 'Text');
```

And you can add multiple lines:

```
Memo.Lines.Add('Line1'#13#10'Line2');
Memo.Lines.AddStrings(ListBox.Lines);
```

Comment: What happens when you add a string containing a line break? Does Lines.Count increase by more than one? In other words, it behaves differently from TStringList?

Comment: I find it easier to use `sLineBreak`

Comment: @David Yes. Memo.Lines.Count increases by 2, or by more when `Memo.WordWrap` is True and text is wrapped over multiple lines.

Comment: I personally hate the way word wrap works, the line count gets distorted, and then when I turn word wrap off, when there's already wrapped lines, it treats them as their own line. Very annoying.

Comment: I can't believe `WordWrap` is relevant. That's display only. If it does what you say that is truly bizarre.

Comment: @David I agree. But it's just how `TMemoStrings` works. I think it would be difficult to get it behave otherwise though, because information of what is added gets lost when it is stored into the Windows control.

Comment: Well I don't necessarily mean distorted, but it creates a line break in certain scenarios, and what was once just one line becomes two or more lines permanently.

Comment: @NGLN TMemoStrings should append text to the EDIT control. It should not modify the text you send.

Comment: @David It does. It writes what you send. Now, how does it read back?

Comment: Well that's not what you said first. You said that behaviour depends on the value of WordWrap.

Comment: Is there somewhere else we can have this discussion? It's a good and interesting topic, but not to comment in an answer like this.

Comment: @NGLN It does not write what you send. I looked at the source. `TMemoStrings` breaks it up into lines. It seems weird to me. It could easily behave differently. It just needs to perform a single `EM_REPLACESEL`. But even then Windows would break it up which is your point. So, I understand now. Seems very strange that the underlying control behaves as it does.

Answer (score 1):

in Delphi has Memo1.Lines.Text

but in C builder has Memo1.Text or Memo1->Text

to let multiple lines into TMemo
you can assigned it as memo1->text = tstringlist->text;

as tstringlist you can use tsringlist->CommaText="line1,line2,line3,line4"; // , as new line

then memo1->text = tstringlist->text;

or memo1->lines->add(tstringlist->text);   //inserting after memo1 where the last line stop

or memo1->lines->add("Line 1, \x0d\x0a line 2, \x0d\x0a line 3");

or memo1->lines->add("Line 1, \r\n aline 2, \r\n aline 3");

else using memo1->lines->add("");  //for each new blank line

good luck

Comment: What has C++ got to do with this?